# What does has kind 'Constraint' mean in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am fresh to Haskell and I am trying to understand the language by writing some code. I am only familiar with very simple instructions on ghci: head, tail, sum, (*), and the like – very simple.

The function I am trying to make is for solving Pythagoras's theorem for vectors of any number of dimensions. This looks something like this: square root (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 ...)

What I can do in ghci in a few lines, which I am trying to make a function is the following:

```
sq x = x*x

b = map sq [1,2,3]

a = sum b

x = sqrt b
```

When I do this I try to include a signature of many sorts,
Currently my function looks like this:

```
mod :: [Num a] => a
mod x = sqrt a
    where a = sum [b]
            where [b] = map sq [x]
```

I do not understand the issue when I try to run it:

```
Expected a constraint, but ‘[Num a]’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type signature:
        Main.mod :: [Num a] => a
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A few things to adjust:

0) `mod` isn't a good name for your function, as it is the name of the modulo function from the standard library. I will call it `norm` instead.

1) The type signature you meant to write is:

```
norm :: Num a => [a] -> a
```

`[a]` is the type of a list with elements of type `a`. The `Num a` before the `=>` isn't a type, but a *constraint*, which specifies that `a` must be a number type (or, more accurately, that it has to be an instance of the `Num` class). `[Num a] =>` leads to the error you have seen because, given the square brackets, the type checker takes it as an attempt to use a list type instead of a constraint.

Beyond the `Num a` issue, you have left out the result type from the signature. The corrected signature reflects that your function takes a list of numbers and returns a number.

2) The `Num a` constraint is too weak for what you are trying to do. In order to use `sqrt`, you need to have not merely a number type, but one that is an instance of `Floating` (cf. leftaroundabout's comment to this answer):

```
GHCi> :t sqrt
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

Therefore, your signature should be

```
norm :: Floating a => [a] -> a
```

3) `[x]` is a list with a single element, `x`. If your argument is already a list, as the type signature says, there is no need to enclose it in square brackets. Your function, then, becomes:

```
norm :: Floating a => [a] -> a
norm x = sqrt a
    where a = sum b
            where b = map sq x
```

Or, more neatly, without the second `where`-block:

```
norm :: Floating a => [a] -> a
norm x = sqrt (sum b)
    where b = map sq x
```

Comment: FTR: despite the name, `Floating` is not really “the class of floating-point numbers”, that would be `RealFloat` (or even [`IEEE`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ieee754-0.7.9/docs/Numeric-IEEE.html#t:IEEE)). It's rather simply the class of _number types you can do calculus with_, also allowing stuff like exact real arithmetic.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks for highlighting that; imprecise statement removed.

Answer (score 13):

As you are aware, values can be classified by their type. `"foo"` has type `[Char]`, `Just 'c'` has type `Maybe Char`, etc.

Similarly, types can be classified by their *kind*. All concrete types for which you can provide a value have kind `*`. You can see this using the `:k` command in GHCi:

```
> :k Int
Int :: *
> :k Maybe Int
Maybe Int :: *
```

Type constructors also have kinds. They are essentially type-valued functions, so their kinds are similar to regular functions.

```
> :t id
id :: a -> a
> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
```

But what is `Num a`? It's not a type, so it doesn't have kind `*`. It's not a type constructor, so it doesn't have an arrow kind. It is something new, so a new kind was created to describe it.

```
> :k Num Int
Num Int :: Constraint
```

And `Num` itself is a `Constraint`-valued function: it takes a value of kind `*` and produces a `Constraint`:

```
> :k Num
Num :: * -> Constraint
```

A thing with kind `Constraint` is used to specify the typeclass that a particular type must be an instance of. It is the value that can occur before `=>` in a type signature. It is also the "argument" to the `instance` "function":

```
instance Num Int where
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining about Constraints. Do all typeclasses give a constraint when applied to appropriate types?

Comment: Yes; a typeclass is essentially a constraint constructor.